# Rendering stops after 1 frame

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

When I render an intro or 3d item it stops after 1 frame. To explain better, when I render a 315 frame intro it only renders the first frame and stops.

Comment: did you press the **animation** button (or Ctrl F12)?

Answer (score 0):

To render every frame in the range, you have to click the 'Animation' button. Otherwise, it will only render the current frame.

[image: Animation button]